# Specify the number of item into a panel with a scrollbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is a picture of what I have right now:

[image]

The problem is that I do not know how to make it smaller, and then use the scrollbar to see the other elements.

I'm using Bootstrap and here is my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
      MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-2 mt-4">
  <p class="text-center mt-5">Matériel souhaité</p>
  <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist" style="overflow-y:scroll">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" role="tab">Ordi 1</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" role="tab">Ordi 2</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" role="tab">Ordi 3</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" role="tab">Ordi 4</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" role="tab">Ordi 1</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" role="tab">Ordi 3</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" role="tab">Ordi 4</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" role="tab">Ordi 1</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" role="tab">Ordi 3</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" role="tab">Ordi 4</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" role="tab">Ordi 1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: an height or a max-height is missing i guess.

Comment: where should I put it ?

Comment: You can test it here where you added  `style="overflow-y:scroll; height:100px"`

Comment: Thanks !!! It's exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

**you can use something like that**

```
   <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" >
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```